# Can a form insert preformatted text within an existing Mediawiki page?

Tags: forms, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I want unskilled users to be able to make a personal entry in a "Member Lookup" page, which I've implemented as a table in standard Mediawiki markup.

I have a large userbase, most of which is not skilled Mediawiki editors. They all have edit *permissions,* just not skill or interest. If I tell them to go edit the raw markup, they won't.

Ideal solution would be a form with a few text boxes and dropdowns, then "Submit" would insert a new text line into the page at a designated spot. Users can be trusted to follow a 'keep clicking submit' instruction if it has to go through a live edit page before committing the change.

I understand this will require an extension. (If I'm wrong, I will be so happy to be corrected.)

Technical limitations:

- IT Policy requires the extension be marked Stable.
- I have sysop but I am not the server admin; I will have to ask an admin to install the extension, and if there are files that have to be configured that cannot be done from within the wiki, I will have to make a request every time.  So ideally, the extension lets me implement forms *from entirely within the wiki* once initial installation is finished.

I've found two promising options so far.  I have trouble determining if the extensions I've found will do the job; they seem focused on creating whole new pages but also promise more flexibility. I also can't tell if they have hidden dependencies or will require a lot of server-side.

- [Semantic Forms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSemantic_Forms)
- [DynamicForms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDynamicForms)

Other stable extensions that look either too limited or require too much server-side (again, I'm happy to be corrected):

- [Input Box](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aInputBox) - seems to only have a predetermined set of form functions
- [FormProc](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFormProc) - not clear on its capabilities, may require server-side?
- Boiler Room and FormInputMik seemed to do something entirely different.
- [List of Form Extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aForm_extensions) - I surfed through and these are the best my research turned up. I could have missed one.

This is not a "which is best" question, though I welcome input on ease of use. The question, short form:

**Will any of the tools I listed actually do the job I described, and if not, do you know of a tool that will?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic Forms is the standard choice for this: it's powerful, actively maintained and well-supported, used by many large sites, and ties into the Semantic MediaWiki ecosystem, so it is easy to build on it if e.g. you need to list the entries, or show them on a map.

I'm not familiar with DynamicForms but I would avoid anything where the version control system is a zip download. Just because it is marked stable (setting that flag is largely up to the author and relying on it too much is a poor IT policy IMO) does not mean that it works with the current version of MediaWiki (I would be surprised if it did, given that the last update to it was five years ago).

Comment: Thanks for the details!  I appreciate you noticing the update date on DynamicForms; I'd missed that.

Comment: I agree that the IT policy is absurd and not particularly well examined. (On the other hand, I'm so glad I'm not in charge of either making or enforcing that class of policy and it is therefore not my problem.)

Comment: Does Semantic Forms require upgrading the entire standard MediaWiki to Semantic MediaWiki? This was one of my concerns, because that would definitely be a blocker.

Comment: The extension page says *Since version 3.0 it can also work without SMW installed*. Probably a lot less useful that way though, since you have no way to list the results.

Comment: Can you define "no way to list the results"? I want to insert the result into a table on the page at the time of the action. Do you mean that would not be possible?

Comment: Semantic Forms uses a one page - one form model. (Semantic MediaWiki basically transforms your wiki into a database of `<page, property, value>` triplets, and Forms uses form fields to provide the property-value pairs for a given page, so using a form multiple times on the same page doesn't really make sense). You can probably abuse it into listing everything on a single page, for example by using [multiple-instance_templates](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/Defining_forms#Multiple-instance_templates), but you'll be swimming upstream. (...)

Comment: (...) The normal way to list things would be via Semantic MediaWiki queries. Those are extremely powerful (if you are familiar with Drupal, think of something like the Views module), but you need to install SMW of course. (I wouldn't call it "upgrading", it's just a normal MediaWiki extension, although certainly a large one.) The Forms extension page claims [Cargo](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo) can be used as a lightweight alternative, but I'm completely unfamiliar with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a lightweight but less user-friendly alternative, you can combine a few tricks to provide an edit link with poor man's forms on a basic MediaWiki:

- use the `section=new` and `nosummary=1` [URL parameters](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Options_affecting_the_edit_form) to make the link append to the end of the page
- create a template to format information, e.g. `Template:Member`:

  ```
  {|
  | Name || {{name}}
  |-
  | Job title || {{job title}}
  |-
  ....
  |}
  ```
- create another template to format instances of the previous template, e.g. `Template:Member preload`:

  ```
  {{ Member
  | name = 
  | job title = 
  ...
  }}
  ```
- use the `preload=Template:Member preload` URL parameter to preload the second template into the edit box.